# Yii2 запретить обновление атрибута

Tags: php, yii2

В общем есть атрибут title к примеру. При вставке записи(action create) ему задается значение, к примеру "Заголовок". Вопрос, как запретить его изменение при обновлении ? Т.е. чтобы при action update он вообще не затрагивался ?

Значение присваевается в beforeSave

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if ( parent::beforeSave($insert) )
    {
        echo 'insert';
        exit();
        $this->title = HtmlPurifier::process( $this->title );
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'update';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю проблема в том что всегда возвращается 'insert'

Comment: Но ведь вас никто насильно не заставляет обновлять абсолютно все поля таблицы

Comment: А подробнее ? У меня значение присваевается в beforeSave. Дополнил вопрос.